# How do I install Eclipse with C++ in Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, installation

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10, and I tried to install Eclipse and C++, but I failed miserably.

I started with an installation from the Software Center, Eclipse worked, but only in Java. Then I started googling for installation guides and tutorials, but after hours of downloads and installations, the C++ in Eclipse still doesn't work.

So now I have two questions:

1. How do I clean up this mess?
   Actually, how do I know if there is a mess?
   According to the Ubuntu Software Center, Eclipse is installed and has three add-ons.
   How do I know if the other installations of other Eclipse versions/packagings overwrote each other or if I have multiple installations?
2. How do I install the latest version of Eclipse and C++ in Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: @MrUniverse: Yes, help with IDEs is one of SO's functions; they are "software tools commonly used by programmers".  The problem with this question is that it needs to be a bit more specific, not that it is off topic.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley oh, sorry. it just seamed.. unrelated, but if there are willing responders, who am i to question.

Comment: I posted the question here because here I found some of the questions on the same topic. Their answers didn't help me, perhaps because they refer to older Eclipse/Ubuntu versions. It's difficult to add details. I worked on it yesterday for 5-6 hours, and I didn't document all the sites I downloaded from and all the steps I went through.

Comment: This is a valid question and it's stated fairly clearly. Did either of you notice how you managed to criticize without providing any helpful information whatsoever? Thanks to the person who actually answered this. I had the same problem and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is a package called `eclipse-cdt` in the Ubuntu 12.10 repositories, this is what you want. If you haven't got `g++` already, you need to install that as well, so all you need is:

`sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++`

Whether you messed up your system with your previous installation attempts depends heavily on how you did it. If you did it the safe way for trying out new packages not from repositories (i.e., only installed in your home folder, no `sudo`s blindly copied from installation manuals...) you're definitely fine. Otherwise, you may well have thousands of stray files all over your file system now. In that case, run all uninstall scripts you can find for the things you installed, then install using `apt-get` and hope for the best.

Comment: I can finally create and compile a c++ project! Thanks. What is the difference between this and installing from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: Nothing - it's just like if you had installed `eclipse`, `eclipse-cdt` and `g++` from the software center :)

Comment: I remember installing CDT a few times, but the c++ never showed up in the new project menu. Perhaps I missed g++. Thanks!

Comment: he can't find the cdt with me, but I know how to install that from the install software menu in eclipse. thanks

Comment: How come this installs Indigo rather than Juno? 
Is there different command for installing Juno?

Answer (score 6):

I used (the suggested answer from above)

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++
```

but ONLY after then also doing

```
sudo eclipse -clean
```

Hope that also helps.

Answer (score 3):

I also tried http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/ in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and works fine!

1. First, I downloaded it from www.eclipse.org/downloads/, choosing Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.
2. I save the file somewhere, let´s say into my home directory. Open a console or terminal, and type:

   `>>cd ~; tar xvzf eclipse*.tar.gz;`
3. Remember for having Eclipse running in Linux, it is required a JVM, so download a jdk file e.g jdk-7u17-linux-i586.rpm (I cann´t post the link due to my low reputation) ... anyway
4. Install the .rpm file following http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Java-on-Linux
5. Find the path to the Java installation, by typing:

   `>>which java`
6. I got /usr/bin/java. To start up Eclipse, type:

   `>>cd ~/eclipse; ./eclipse -vm /usr/bin/java`

Also, once everything is installed, in the home directory, you can double-click the executable icon called eclipse, and then you´ll have it!. In case you like an icon, create a .desktop file in  /usr/share/applications:

```
>>sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

The .desktop file content is as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=Eclipse  
Type=Application  
Exec="This is the path of the eclipse executable on your machine"  
Terminal=false 
Icon="This is the path of the icon.xpm file on your machine"  
Comment=Integrated Development Environment  
NoDisplay=false  
Categories=Development;IDE  
Name[en]=eclipse.desktop
```

Best luck!

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same boat. Installed Eclipse, realized need CDT.

sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt g++

This just adds the CDT package on top of existing installation - no un-installation etc. required.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/
^Give that a try

I have not used the CDT for eclipse but I do use Eclipse Java for Ubuntu 12.04 and it works wonders.

Comment: This was one of the many installations I tried, and didn't work.